# Use wxthread to update content of wxframe in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, wxwidgets

I am a newbie in using threads. I have developed a program in `C++` using `wxwidgets` to show the  count of packets received through the network interface. What I have done so far is: I have a `wxbutton` in a `wxdialog`. On clickng on the button a `wxframe`  containing `wxgrid` is opened. The `wxgrid` contains info like interface name, packets in and packets out.

Now what I need is to constantly update the packets in and packets out fields. I have a function that calculates the packets in and packets out. So I think I need to execute the function continuously until the user closes the `frame`.

I hope `wxthread` can be utilized to perform this. But have no idea on how to start with or how a function can be executed from a thread. Can someone please guide me.. THANK YOU

Comment: did you try to look at the wxWidgets documentation? Is there something that is not clear?

Comment: @Igor: I did..But I Didnt understand how to implement it in the way  I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A worker thread can't access any GUI object directly, so you need to post events to the main thread where you can define event handlers for them which will do whatever you need. There is a convenient base class for such events called `wxThreadEvent` that you may find useful.

Alternatively, and especially if you use C++11, you could use [CallAfter()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.0/classwx_evt_handler.html#a63c7351618fd77330d80a250b3719519) which allows you to execute a callback in the main thread context. This is especially nice with C++11 lambdas because it allows you to keep all your code in the same place without having to extract it into a separate event handler.

Comment: The thread sample distributed with wxWidgets itself shows the use of `wxThreadEvent`. Examples of `CallAfter()` can be found in the [blog post about it](http://wxwidgets.blogspot.com/2013/01/about-benefits-of-procrastination.html), albeit it's used for a different purpose there.